# Getting the first index of a array does not move

Tags: java, arrays, random

I Insert code and explain the problem:

```
public static void nextPermutationArray(int[] v) {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    Random r = new Random();

    while (x < v.length) {

        y = x + r.nextInt(v.length - x);

        int temp = v[x];
        v[x] = v[y];
        v[y] = temp;

        x++;
    }
}
public static void printArray(int[] v) {
    for (int i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(v[i]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] a = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    int[] b = new int[]{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    nextPermutationArray(a);
    printArray(a);
    nextPermutationArray(a);
    printArray(a);
    nextPermutationArray(a);
    printArray(a);
    nextPermutationArray(a);
    printArray(a);

    //IntegerPermutation.permutation(a, a.length);
}
```

The output can be:

> run:
>
> 1046532
>
> 3415620
>
> 3052614
>
> 3021564

I want it to be in such a way for example, the important thing is that the index 0 is the first:

> run:
>
> 0146532
>
> 0415623
>
> 0352614
>
> 0321564

Comment: What is `nextPermutationArray` and what do you expect it to do?

Comment: @Eran I'm sorry I forgot to put it, I updated it

Comment: @BruceCollie sry, i update it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excluding the first index of the array from the permutation is simple enough:

```
public static void nextPermutationArray(int[] v) {
    int x = 1; // changed this line
    int y = 0;
    Random r = new Random();

    while (x < v.length) {

        y = x + r.nextInt(v.length - x);

        int temp = v[x];
        v[x] = v[y];
        v[y] = temp;

        x++;
    }
}
```